# How do I return values from a SELECT on an MVC3 form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC3 form. My source code looks like this:

```
<input id="Status_RowKey" name="Status.RowKey" size="10" type="text" value="" />
<select class="editor-select" id="StatusDescription" name="Status.Description"style="width: 99%">
  <option value="ABC">abc</option>
  <option value="DEF">def</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that it seems the value of Status.Description is never getting sent back. It's just NULL and all the other values on the form are sent back. I change the value it appears changed but never gets sent.  When it's a select do I have to do something different to return the value selected?

Comment: The value will be getting posted back (you can use a tool such as Fiddler to check exactly what data your browser is sending) it's probably an issue with model binding. Did you use Html.DropDownListFor() to create the <select>? What does the signature of your Action method look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `var myValue = Request.Form["Status.Description"]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following view models (and if you don't you could define them):

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action to which this form is POSTed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "Status")]StatusViewModel model)
{
    // model.RowKey and model.Description will be correctly bound here
    ...
}
```

You can also using a wrapping view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public StatusViewModel Status { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // model.Status.RowKey and model.Status.Description will be correctly bound here
    ...
}
```